# create a drive based on the name of the active layer

Tags: scripting, add-on, layers

I saw this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-lGco8mDiw&ab_channel=aVersionOfReality
It explains how to use a py script to retrieve the layer number to use that value in a driver or something. The problem is that I have to constantly Update Dependencies, sometimes several times, for it to work properly. When I save the file and reopen it, nothing works anymore. It doesn't matter how many times I Update Dependencies or relaunch the script.

Originally, I wanted to use this script on all my files. I thought I'd just have to convert it into an addon to be able to retrieve my layer number from any file. I've used chatgpt to convert it to an addon, but it doesn't work.

My questions:
How can I retrieve my layer number in a variable for use in a driver?
How can I do this for all my files?
How can I get a script to run automatically each time I reopen a file?

Thanks in advance

```py
#Set layer name to start with a number then :, eg '1: Layer'
#Drive a value in a material node with expression: layer_number(depsgraph)
#The driven value will be the number at the beginning of the layer name
#Doesn't always update when switching layers, might have to Update Dependencies
#Muting/Unmuting the node will also cause an update
#Seems to always update on Render
#by aVersionOfReality.com, twitter@aversionreality


import bpy

def layer_number(depsgraph: bpy.types.Depsgraph):
    name = depsgraph.view_layer.name
    
    try:
        layer_no = int(name.split(':')[0])
    except:
        layer_no = 0
    
    #print ('name =', name, 'number =', layer_no)
    
    return layer_no

def register():
    bpy.app.driver_namespace['layer_number'] = layer_number

register()
```

Comment: What is a "layer *number*"?

Comment: You need to convert it to an addon use the load_post handler and use the @persistent decorator. see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.load_post https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.persistent

Comment: or you can directly type into the field `#int(self.name.split(':')[0])`. You do have to check "Use Self" in the driver settings though

Comment: It seems you are talking about view layers and retrieving a number from their names. You should state that clearly in your question so people don't need to read the code to know what you are talking about. The title should communicate what the question is about. It might also be agood idea to provide context and explain what you are trying to do with those numbers in a driver.